# T-SQL WHERE NOT IN not catching NULL values

Tags: t-sql, null, where-clause

This is my code:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    RecordID BIGINT,
    RecordValue NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE(RecordID,RecordValue)
VALUES  (1,'100')
       ,(2,NULL)
       ,(3,'200')
       ,(4,NULL)
       ,(5,'200')

SELECT RecordID,RecordValue
FROM @TABLE
WHERE RecordValue NOT IN ('200')
```

OUTPUT:

1  100

Desire OUTPUT:

1 100

2 NULL

4 NULL

How can I get the 'NULL' values too?

Actually, my the sql statement is generated by a lot of procedures and functions, I am limited in doing operations like using ISNULL function. The final statement is in the following format:

```
WHERE RecordValue NOT IN ('CSV...') 
WHERE RecordValue IN ('CSV...') 
or combinatnation from both 
RecordValue NOT IN ('CSV...') AND RecordValue IN ('CSV...')
```

Is there a way to get NULL values too in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT RecordID,RecordValue 
FROM @TABLE 
WHERE RecordValue NOT IN ('200') OR RecordValue IS NULL
```

When value is `NULL` then comparison with it is always `NULL` so you have to take it into account.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to change the procedures in order to generated this code.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
SELECT RecordID,RecordValue
FROM @TABLE
WHERE ISNULL(RecordValue,'') NOT IN ('200')
```